# receive array from model to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

In my model I'm creating a random variable called $token and i am retrieving user_id from query,

```
login_valid($username, $password){
    $this->db-> query( "INSERT INTO user_auth (id, token,expired_at)VALUES('$id', '$token', '$expired_at');");
    $token = crypt(substr(md5(rand()),0,7), $salt);
    $var1= $q->row()->id;
    $var2 = $token;
    return array($var1, $var2);
}
```

but in my controller i have to write the model function twice to recieve both variables such as,

```
  $login_id =$this->loginmodel->login_valid($username, $password)[0];
  $token =$this->loginmodel->login_valid($username, $password)[1];
```

is there any alternate way of doing this?
Thank you for your responce.

Comment: why don't u create token in controller and pass it to model to insert

Comment: by the way $token variable should above the insert query in login_valid model

Comment: i am new to ci, i learnt everything related to server should be done in model? should i create token in controller instead?

Comment: of course u can

Comment: okay ..thanks pradeep you have been a great help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need [list](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_list.asp), try the following

```
list($login_id, $token) = $this->loginmodel->login_valid($username, $password);
```